# Nunjucks Async Rendering with Keystone View

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, keystonejs, nunjucks

In an `Express`-based app, I'm running an async function to fetch image source from a database and render them into a `Nunjucks` view engine

Nunjucks is rendering the following in the DOM

```
<img src="[object Promise]">
```

I have already [enabled Nunjucks's async rendering](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#configure) with `web: { async: true }` and [enabled the nunjucks async api with a callback](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#asynchronous-support) like so

```
// controller.js (KeystoneJS app)
view.render('index', function (err, res) {
    console.log('err at index render', err); // undefined
    return res;
});
```

How can i get the resolved value of my async function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, Nunjucks doesn't support asynchronous render directly. You can use asynchronous filters to get it. Maybe I'm wrong.

Imho, use feature with `Be Careful!` mark is a not good idea.

---

```
// template.njk
Hello {{user_id | find | attr('name') }}!

// app.js
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

// Async filter
env.addFilter('find', function(a, cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        cb(null, {
            name: 'Smith'
        });
    }, 10);
}, true)

// Sync filter
env.addFilter('attr', function(obj, attr) {
    return obj && attr && obj[attr];
});

env.render('template.njk', 
    {user_id: 1}, // pass sync vars
    function(err, res) {
        if (err)
           return;

        console.log(res);
        return res
    }
);
```

Comment: Yes, i went with your idea to use filter instead of direct render instead. However, i thought that enabling `web: {async: true}` could possibly enable direct async render as described in the [Nunjucks Docs](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#configure)

Comment: Imho, `web: ...` option enables async loader, not a render.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `nunjucks`, but you can implement `async` functionality regardless of the view engine being used. To show the idea, I tried to reproduce your situation. I created an HTML file named `index.html` with an `img` tag without any `src` attribute:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <title>Reproduce</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id='bg'></img>
        <script src='./so.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a `<script>` tag in my HTML which links to my `so.js` file shown below by which an image is requested by sending a HTTP request to NodeJS/Express server:

```
getImage();

function getImage(){

    // Get an image by its name as URL parameter
    fetch('/bg/background.jpg',{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(result=>{
        return result.blob()
    }).then(result=>{
        console.log('result -> ', result)
        document.querySelector('#bg').src=URL.createObjectURL(result)
        document.querySelector('#bg').style.width='200px'
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('err -> ', err)
    })
}
```

Here is my NodeJS/ExpressJS code inside a file name `server.js`:

```
express=require('express')
bodyParser=require('body-parser')
path=require('path')
fetch=require('node-fetch')

server=express()

//Body-parser middleware
server.use(bodyParser.json())
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
server.use(bodyParser.raw())

//Set static path
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))

server.get('/',(req,res)=>{
        res.render('index.html')
})

// Pick a file on hard disk
// and  send it as "Blob" to the browser
server.get('/bg/:name',(req,res)=>{
    var options = {
        root: __dirname + '/public/',
        dotfiles: 'deny',
        headers: {
            'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
            'x-sent': true
        }
    };

    var fileName = req.params.name;
    res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Sent:', fileName);
        }
    });
})

server.listen('8000',()=>{
        console.log('Server listening on port 8000...')
})
```

---

As can be seen, I'm doing my `async` communication between browser and server by implementing `fetch API` and without even touching the view engine.

**I just wanted to provide an alternative idea** to use `fetch API` and do the `async` HTTP communications with it regardless of any view rendering engine that is being used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need to do this via the view engine as i need to render all images in my website asynchronously, so placing these selectors would be too tedious a solution for me. Nonetheless, this is a good alternative for others looking for a `async` render